# Taking a departure from a transit country's airport one hour later after my visa expires

Tags: transit, airports, visa-expiration

I am from Turkey and I will have a Schengen visa to go to an academic conference to be held in France. The only flight option for me to take into consideration is taking off from Istanbul, going through the Amsterdam airport and then arriving in Bordeaux. And then I will come back to my homeland the other way around, flying from Bordeaux to Amsterdam and then from Amsterdam to Istanbul.

I am going to book the flight and I will get the Schengen visa for April 6 - 14. However, my return flight from Amsterdam to Istanbul will take off on April 15, 01:15 AM. That is, it would exceed the Schengen visa validity date limit by only one hour and fifteen minutes and I will be waiting at the airport in this time interval.

Would they allow me to get the Schengen visa in this condition? Or would they reject giving me the visa? Even if they allow me to get the visa, would it cause a problem at the airport, a transit area, just because I overstay at the airport in the Netherlands for just one hour waiting for the plane to take off?

I do not need a transit visa for the Netherlands by the way, I have been told by the authorities that I need the visa for France only FYI.

Comment: Let others with experience answer. But if you clear the emigration, only that counts. Take off time is not counted.

If you cleared the emigration, on the country's record, you have complied with the visa policy.

Comment: You do not need a transit visa because France and the Netherlands are both in the Schengen Area, so a visa valid for one is (in most cases) valid for the other. But why ask for a visa ending on the 14th when you could simply ask for one ending on the 15th? Or even a couple days later just in case? I’m not even sure they do visas that short anyway, do they?

Comment: Why would you ask for a visa for a period shorter than you need? Is there something you're not telling us?

Comment: As far as I know, Schengen area airports have an exit immigration control, so it may be that if you pass through that before your visa expires, it *should* be fine. (On the other hand, it won't be fine for countries without exit control, such as the US.)

Comment: Your plan allows no contingency if for any reason you can’t leave on that flight - it could be cancelled by the airline due to a technical problem for example. Why not ask for a slightly longer visa?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the answers. I could have handled the issue and the problem had been resolved this way: First, I thought they were going to give me a visa only for nine days. However, anyway, they themselves had offered and provided me with a longer visa duration of approximately one month. By the way, sorry for the late reply.